# Unable to find correct language.dat

Tags: babel, languages, hyphenation

I have installed the portable version of MikTeX 2.9 on a PC without administrator rights. I try to use the package Dutch babel, but it gives the common error of

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for (label) the language 'Dutch' (babel) I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\begin{document}
Doesn't work with or without text.
\end{document}
```

I searched for all language.dat files on my external hard drive AND my pc and placed the line 'dutch nehyph.tex', 'dutch nehyph2.tex' (found that in another language.dat file) in it, but it keeps giving the error.

If I try to check the box for the language via the MiKTeX options, it says:

> This language is not yet available

Comment: Double click on miktex-portable.cmd in the miktex folder. This should give you a small miktex menu in the tray. Start from there miktex-options and change the languages in the language tab. Btw: A normal miktex can be installed without problems on a pc without admin rights. Simply choose as installation folder a folder where you have writing rights.

Comment: Make sure that you have the relevant packages installed: Start the package manager, synchronize the repository and then look for packages with "dutch", "hyphen" etc. Also changing language.dat doesn't work as miktex overwrites it. You must adapt language.ini if you really want to do it manually.

Comment: If I try to synchronize the package manager, I get the error: host not found; get host name failed in tcp_connect(). If I search for babel-Dutch, it says that it is already installed.
How should I adapt the language.ini to get the correct language? It is now '[dutch] attributes= ', while other languages have attributes=exclude

Comment: I can try to de-install and re-install babel-Dutch, but I have to do that elsewhere at another WiFi connection. Another reason that I don't install on the C-drive is because it asks, for every map I paste, if I really want to do it, so that will take a long time to do

Comment: Well I checked on a portable miktex I had somewhere, and switching a language destroyed the language.ini. But I don't have the time now to check if an update would resolve the problem.

Comment: After an update the `languages.ini` was corrected, but changing something in the language tab destroys it again. So a backup should be done. If you can't get a sensible ini ask me per mail, I can sent you mine. You should also make a bug report on the miktex site.

Comment: You should also upgrade to a recent version of `babel`. The message shown was changed long ago, so an old version is being used. That won't fix your issue, I think, but there are lots of bug fixes.

Comment: I haven't got time yet to re-install babel, but my MiKTeX Package Manager says that babel is up-to-date. When I first started using this pc, I installed a lot of the packages manually, so that might give some problems with older versions

Comment: I updated babel from version 3.8m (manually installed) to 3.9l (via the MPM), but still get the same error:
No hyphenation patterns where preloaded for(babel) the language 'Dutch' into the format.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried using different languages, but english seems to be the only one that works, either with "attributes=" or "attributes=exclude"

Comment: @Tom: As I already wrote miktex portable seems to destroy the language.ini. I already made a bug report. If you can't get a sensible language.ini, contact me per mail so that I send you mine. Regarding babel: You problably must rebuild the  formats after an update.

Answer (score 0):

In the path `<your-install-dir>\texmfs\install\tex\latex` browse for the folder containig the appropriate babel language packages, like `babel-dutch`. Alternatively get the appropriate `*.ldf` files from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-dutch).

Copy the folder content to `<your-install-dir>\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel-<language>`. Try to recompile your document.