# hyphenation for language ngerman doesn't work in TeXnicCenter/MiKTeX

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation, german

**Hello everyone!**

I have a problem writing my master's thesis and I hope someone can help.
I am using TeXnicCenter 2.02 in combination with MiKTeX 2.9.4248. 
The Header of my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{amsthm} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\usepackage{titlesec} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{hyphsubst} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}



\begin{document}



    Text of my document... 




\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the hyphenation is incorrect. For example the German word "Optimierungsproblem" at the end of one line is separated to 
"Optimierungsprob- 
lem" 
instead of the correct way 
"Optimierungspro- 
blem"

and there is one Warning with the message:

"pdflatex > Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for the language ngerman into the Format. Please, configure your TeX System to add them and rebuild the Format. Now I will use the Patterns preloaded for \language=0 instead of Input line 42"

The Input lines 41, 42 and 43 (of the ngerman.ldf file) look like this:

```
41 \ifx\l@ngerman\@undefined

42 \@nopatterns{ngerman}

43 \adddialect\l@ngerman0
```

The german hyphenation package is installed in MiKTeX. I've tried to find an answer in other questions and someone suggested to add the line "ngerman loadhyph-de-1996.tex" to the language.dat file. So I checked the language.dat file but the following lines are all included:

```
54 ngerman loadhyph-de-1996.tex

55 ngerman-x-2014-05-21 dehyphn-x-2014-05-21.tex

56 =ngerman-x-latest
```

Can anyone help me regarding this problem? 
If I need to add a log file or other information, please let me know.

Best regards,
Dom

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: As an aside, you also need the T1 font encoding for the hyphenating to work properly on words with diacritics (umlauts, etc.), that is to say you should put `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in your preamble as well.

Comment: In miktex settings check the status of the ngerman language(s). In case that you have the portable miktex: be aware that there is a bug so don't change anything, ask back first.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I will have a look at the starter guide. I also included \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} in the Header now. And yes, I am using the portable miktex. How can I fix this bug? Best regards

Comment: You can't fix the bug. See https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2342/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217523/problems-finding-correct-language-dat. If you destroyed your language.ini you need a new one. Try if you find one here im miktex-misc: http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-misc.tar.lzma

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this package seems to be damaged. I will try to get a new miktex-hyph-german package. Is the language.ini a file that is included in these packages?

Comment: No, language.ini is a file that contains entries for all languages so it is not in a language package. Mail me if you can't extract it and I give you mine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you give an answer here? Or is this a duplicate to the linked question?

Comment: @Johannes_B: it's (probably) a duplicate and a miktex bug.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Pity that there are no news from Christian yet.

Comment: @Johannes_B he has been doing quite a lot work on miktex in the past weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Some German words just cannot be hyphenated properly by the package. Especially those that consists actually of two or more words. For these words use:

```
\hyphenation{Ele-men-tar-ob-jek-te Op-ti-mie-rungs-pro-blem}
```

Seperate the words with a space character, like in the example.

Edit 1:

A full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{hyphsubst} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\hyphenation{Ele-men-tar-ob-jek-te Op-ti-mie-rungs-pro-blem}

\begin{document}

Text of my document... 

\end{document}
```

Edit 2:

See [here](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_Silbentrennung). Sorry, it's German, but it's meant to help the author.

Comment: Though this answers the question, it doesn't answer the question. There is (was) a very specific bug in MikTeX, fixing that is the solution to the problem (no hyphenation patterns loaded).

Comment: Yes, but the original question was how to hyphenate the word "Optimierungsproblem". According to the link I gave, hyphenation doesn't work with compounded words and this word is a compound.

Comment: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/558/tex-wie-funktioniert-hyphenation

Comment: Sorry, the question is not how to hyphenate the word *Optimierungsproblem*. The question is how to get ngerman hyphenation patterns in MikTeX, because there was a bug at the time.

Comment: Ok, I guess you're right. So I just gave a helpful alternative if the bug cannot be fixed. But I doesn't matter as this question is from march (which I didn't see at first).